# How to keep Excel from using absolute addresses when clicking a cell while in a "range selection" window?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, cells

In any version of Excel (since 2000, at least), you can enter `=` into a cell to indicate that a formula is about to be entered and then click cell A1 so that the formula says `=A1`.  This is a relative address and is the behavior I would expect.

However, there are those special "range selection" windows that behave differently.  For example, go to create a new conditional format that uses a formula.  While the formula window is open, clicking on cell A1 results in `=$A$1` being entered into the formula box.  This is very annoying because it prevents you from doign a select/drag or copy/paste if you want to repeat that conditional format elsewhere.

**It's not just the conditional format feature that does this**, but other Excel features that implement this behavior.

I would like Excel to treat point-and-click formula designers to use relative addresses rather than absolute addresses.  Does Excel have such a feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not been able to find a way to turn this feature on/off. A way to deal with it is to do the following;

After you select your range, press the <kbd>F4</kbd> to change the reference. Press it again to change to the next type of reference and so forth. In the example you gave for conditional formatting, pressing it 3 times gets you to relative reference.

Comment: I just confirmed that this works, although you do need to hit F4 every time you click a cell rather than choosing your reference format once so that all consecutive clicks will use that same format.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I've just checked this out. I'd never actually realised it. This behaviour also occurs when set to R1C1 mode as well. It **doesn't** happen when editing a formula from the formula bar (e.g. when entering a formula in a cell).

I do not believe that there is any way of controlling this.

I suggest though, asking in one of the Microsoft recommended support forums:

- http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/excel?auth=1

These 2 require logins, I think you have to be a business partner or Technet/MSDN subscriber

- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/category/officeitpro
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exceldev/threads

Alternatively, if you get paid support from Microsoft you can try asking them directly:
http://support.microsoft.com/ph/918

Comment: Please don't mark down without leaving a comment!

Comment: I didn't mark you down, but my guess is it was because you didn't really answer the question. Although your information may be helpful, it probably should have been posted as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Cheers for the info @CharlieRB, though I think that it would have been pretty impossible to add that info as a comment!